# Posting and getting from php via jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, post, get

**Update, I changed jQuery to this and it still doesn't work:**

```
    $("#click").click(function(){
    $.post("accountcreation.php",function(response){ userCreation:"userCreation" 
        $("#justtesting").html(response);
    })
})
```

Nothing is happening. I had the HTML and PHP working, but then I wanted to add live updating and began this jQuery code. What's wrong with it?

Thanks.

jQuery

```
$("#click").click(function(){
    $.post("accountcreation.php", { userCreation:"userCreation" 
    })
    $.get("accountcreation.php", function(data,status){
        $("#justtesting").html(data);
    })
})
```

HTML

```
Username: <input required type="text" name="userCreation" 
onchange="userValidate();" 
onkeypress="this.onchange();" 
onpaste="this.onchange();" 
oninput="this.onchange();">
<span id="userRegexJavascriptResponse"></span>
<br>

<input type="button" value="Submit" id="click">


<div id="justtesting"></div>
```

PHP (Part)

```
class accountcreation {
    private $options;

    function __construct($con, $ipCreation) {
        $this->passwordCreation = $_POST['passwordCreation'];
        $this->userCreation = $_POST['userCreation'];
        $this->ipCreation = $ipCreation;
        $this->emailCreation = $_POST['emailCreation'];
        $this->con = $con;
    }
```

Comment: there is no event `onClick` in jquery. http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: I changed it to "click," I still get no result.

Comment: You should be receiving the data in the [`post` success handler](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).

Comment: @showdev I updated the script, no joy yet.

Comment: You've not yet got the right syntax. Check out [this example](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#example-5).

Comment: syntax is all wrong in updated `$.post`. Use your browser console to check for errors!

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)

Comment: @showdev  `$("#click").click(function){
 $.post( "test.php", { name: "John" })
 .done(function( data ) {
 alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
 });
});` `<?php if(isset($name)) { echo $name; } ?>` also failed, which I took from your link. :(

Comment: [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d1wLa8s8/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code instead. Your PHP script is expecting data via post, and you can get a response in that same `.post()` call.

```
$("#click").click(function(){
    $.post("accountcreation.php", { userCreation:"userCreation"}, function(data){
        $("#justtesting").html(data);
    });
});
```

**NOTE:** I would strongly advise against inline `javascript`; it's so difficult to maintain and is just not good practice. Event listeners should be attached as above ... that's the way to go.

Your HTML should be:

```
Username: <input required type="text" name="userCreation">
<span id="userRegexJavascriptResponse"></span><br>
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="click">
<div id="justtesting"></div>
```

And, you do need to include **jQuery core** right before the **JavaScript** code:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
```

If you open your dev tools and run the code snippet below, you should see a post call being made with the data you supply. This means that it should be able to work on your server or else you should be able to see any errors in the console of the dev tools.

```js
   $("#click").click(function(){
        $.post("accountcreation.php", { userCreation:"userCreation"}, function(data){
            $("#justtesting").html(data);
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Username: <input required type="text" name="userCreation">
    <span id="userRegexJavascriptResponse"></span><br>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="click">
    <div id="justtesting"></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything, either. Is the click function wrong, perhaps? It's supposed to mate with this: `<input type="button" value="Submit" id="click">`

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/H5csicO.jpg and http://i.imgur.com/Up1Wqy6.jpg <-- Still, nothing happens...

Comment: @icor103 Check your browser console for javascript errors. It looks like you've got some HTML (a `<div>`) inside your `<script></script>` tags.

Comment: @showdev .. That's embarassing, thank you. I would use console, but I can never get the dang thing to work very well. Is there a browser/plugin that you suggest?

Comment: @icor103 I've gotten used to [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). But most [modern browsers](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) have [some equivalent](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/).

Comment: @showdev Firebug is the one I tried first, it always gave me no data at all.. Maybe the version I'm using is all screwed up.